# User GPO not showing in gpresult

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain, domain-controller, users

I have a GPO that maps a drive for users. I have tested it and it works for a newly created test user.

Settings are: User Configurations > Pref > Windows Settings > Drive Maps : **SETTINGS**

The issue: Some users do not get the drive!

**Troubleshooting**: perform a **gpresult /r** to see what is up.
Result: GPO's are not showing AT ALL in the report?!

OK so I verify user location in AD: *DOMAIN.local*>*compOU*>*usersOU*>**USER**

**USER** is member of group: **TESTGROUP**

In GPM the scope of the GPO is: Links: **DOMAIN.local\compOU\usersOU**

Security filtering: **TESTGROUP**

No WMI filtering

Why is the policy no applying, or at least showing up ?

Comment: Do Authenticated Users have read permission?

Comment: Under "Delegation" authenticated users is not defined, but the TESTGROUP is defined as having "Read" and "Apply group policy" as allow.

Comment: Check for the loop back policy ... If you have it in the environment then just disable it for a while and then check ur new GPO...

Comment: Are all the users members of the UsersOU? are all users members of the TestGroup?

Answer (score 1):

Authenticated Users must have read permission on the Delegation tab. This allows the computer to read the GPO, which is required even though it is for user settings.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but how do you then explain how the testuser is able to get the policy ?

Comment: Have just verified that the "Authenticated users" don't need the have read on the delegations tab, only the user has read permissions and no computer objects are defined, still applies correctly to the test user